# How to change selected text color locally - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Text **selection** color can be changed by globally setting the theme:

```
    theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
        accentColor: kPrimaryAccent,
        primaryColor: kPrimaryColor,
        textSelectionColor: kTextSelectionColor,
        textSelectionHandleColor: kPrimaryAccent)
```

But how can this be done **locally** in a single text-field?

Comment: The text field has a property called "style", there you would be able to change the color.  https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-deep-dive-into-flutter-textfields-f0e676aaab7a#:~:text=Text%20Style%2C%20Alignment%20and%20Cursor,the%20cursor%20inside%20the%20TextField.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the property mentioned in [Mobina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9902765/mobina) answer become deprecated, here is how you do it in early 2022:

```dart
Container(
  child: Theme(
    data: ThemeData(
      textSelectionTheme: const TextSelectionThemeData(
        cursorColor: Colors.yellow,
        selectionColor: Colors.green,
        selectionHandleColor: Colors.blue,
      )
    ),
    child: SelectableText(
      'this is a text',
    ),
  ),
),
```

Source: [TextSelectionTheme migration](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/text-selection-theme)

Answer (score 2):

[update] You can wrap your widget with a `Theme` and set the `textSelectionTheme` for its `ThemeData`:

```
Container(
  child: Theme(
    data: ThemeData(
      textSelectionTheme: TextSelectionThemeData(
        selectionColor: AppColors.accent,
      ),
    ),
    child: SelectableText(
      'this is a text',
    ),
  ),
),
```

Or just add `textSelectionTheme` to your `ThemeData` class if you use some.

Comment: This is now deprecated.

Comment: Do you know how to do this now, that the above is deprecated

Comment: From the documentation _"Use TextSelectionThemeData.selectionColor instead. This feature was deprecated after v1.26.0-18.0.pre."_